# finding out the train station based on train arrival and departure in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, date

I have to find out the train station in which the trains have arrived in the present day and have departed the next day, For example a train arrived at 11:55 PM but departed at 12:10 AM. I have to make a list of all the stations that fall into this scenario in MYSQL and the arrival and departure is given in minutes in data base. The imp. columns are train_route_id (int11), station_code (varchar255), p_arrival_minute (int11), p_departure_minute (int11). Below is a sample table
0 is 12 AM and 566 is 9:26 AM

```
train_route_id  station_code  p_arrival_min  p_departure_min
 491374           ABC            566            568
 491374           DEF            586            590    
 491374           GHI            606            615
 491374           JKL            646            650
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM train_route_points
WHERE
    -- Train arrived today and departed or departing next day
    (
        DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL p_arrival_minute / 60 MINUTE) = CURDATE()
        AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL p_departure_minute / 60 MINUTE) > CURDATE()
    )
    OR
    (
        DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL p_arrival_minute / 60 MINUTE) < CURDATE()
        AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL p_departure_minute / 60 MINUTE) = CURDATE()
    )
```

I tried this but didn't got anywhere with it.

Comment: Maybe you could [edit] your question and post the structure of [database] table `train_route_points`, i.e. the column names and their data-types?

Comment: Also could you please provide some sample data to work with. Current scenario is like shooting arrows blindly.

Comment: Provide sample data according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: *```DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL p_arrival_minute / 60 MINUTE) = CURDATE()```* ??? You add some minutes to current date obtaining datetime. Then you compare this result with current date. If added minutes amount is not zero then you'd receive FALSE obviously.

Comment: I am a beginner. Having trouble with this.

Comment: *For example a train arrived at 11:55 PM but departed at 12:10 PM.* The values in this case are 1435 and 1450 accordingly? If so then it is enough to check that the arrival value is less than 24*60=1440 whereas the departure value is 1440 or above. Or, if the values are adjusted/truncated, then you'd simpy cleck that arrival value is greater than departure value. And you do not need in any datetime operations. From the other side if the train arrives today and departs tomorrow and the gap is over 24 hours then you cannot find this in the latter case.

Comment: You can't tell by minutes alone; you need date too. Not even looking for departure minutes greater than arrival works, because a train could arrive at 00:01 and leave the next day at 00:02. And if you have date you don't need minutes. The question as posed is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simple number comparison with `1440 (24*60)` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM train_route_points 
WHERE p_arrival_min < 1440
  AND p_departure_min >= 1440;
```

Comment: I bet, no value in that table is >= 1440

Comment: there are few value of p_departure_minute which are in 1500s and there is another which is 2400.

Comment: 1440 is nothing but number of minutes in a day. so your 1500 and 2400 will be on next day so where is the issue? You can provide us more sample data in your question to get efficient answer.